# grid-auto-flow: dense makes element width really small

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Hi I was playing around with css grid, specially with the grid-auto-flow: dense property and everything seems to work  fine, the only problem is that when you make your browser really small some rows collapse to be really small in width. Any idea why this might be happening? for example here the long purple div just disappears.

```css
body {
  background: mediumaquamarine;
}

.u-ptb40 {
  padding: 40px 0;
}

.container {
  max-width:960px;
  margin: 0 auto;

  /* grid */
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 20px;
}

.tile {
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.work__wrap {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(calc(860px / 6), 1fr));
  grid-gap: 20px;
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(calc(860px / 6), auto);
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
}

.two-by-two {
  background: pink;
  grid-column-end: span 2;
  grid-row-end: span 2;
}

.one-by-three {
  background: mediumslateblue;
  grid-row-end: span 3;
}

.three-by-two {
  background: lightgoldenrodyellow;
  grid-column-end: span 3;
  grid-row-end: span 2;
}

.one-by-one {
  background: salmon;
}

.one-by-two {
  background: lightgreen;
  grid-row-end: span 2;
}

.two-by-one {
  background: lightskyblue;
  grid-column-end: span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="">
  <div class="container work__wrap u-ptb40">
    <div class="tile two-by-two">
    </div>
    <div class="tile one-by-three">
    </div>
    <div class="tile three-by-two">
    </div>
    <div class="tile one-by-one">
    </div>
    <div class="tile one-by-two">
    </div>
    <div class="tile two-by-two">
    </div>
    <div class="tile one-by-one">
    </div>
    <div class="tile one-by-one">
    </div>
    <div class="tile one-by-one">
    </div>
    <div class="tile one-by-one">
    </div>
    <div class="tile three-by-two">
    </div>
    <div class="tile one-by-one">
    </div>
    <div class="tile two-by-one">
    </div>
    <div class="tile two-by-one">
    </div>
    <div class="tile one-by-one">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also I would like to know if there is a way to make the transition more fluid, sort of like the one in pinterest when you can see the tiles rearranging. Thanks.

**EDIT**

This is what I don't like, 1fr width colums getting small.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not caused by `grid-auto-flow: dense`.

The problem is the result of a grid item having no inherent width, so it just collapses on smaller screens.

You have this:

```
.one-by-three {
   grid-row-end: span 3;
   background: mediumslateblue;
}
```

Instead, try this:

```
.one-by-three {
   grid-row-end: span 3;   
   grid-column-end: span 2;  /* new, for example */
   background: mediumslateblue;
}
```

**OR**, just add content.

```css
body {
  background: mediumaquamarine;
}

.u-ptb40 {
  padding: 40px 0;
}

.container {
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  /* grid */
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 20px;
}

.tile {
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.work__wrap {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(calc(860px / 6), 1fr));
  grid-gap: 20px;
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(calc(860px / 6), auto);
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
}

.two-by-two {
  background: pink;
  grid-column-end: span 2;
  grid-row-end: span 2;
}

.one-by-three {
  grid-column-end: span 3; /* new */
  grid-row-end: span 3;
  background: mediumslateblue;
  
}

.three-by-two {
  background: lightgoldenrodyellow;
  grid-column-end: span 3;
  grid-row-end: span 2;
}

.one-by-one {
  background: salmon;
}

.one-by-two {
  background: lightgreen;
  grid-row-end: span 2;
}

.two-by-one {
  background: lightskyblue;
  grid-column-end: span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="">
  <div class="container work__wrap u-ptb40">
    <div class="tile two-by-two">test</div>
    <div class="tile one-by-three">test</div>
    <div class="tile three-by-two">test</div>
    <div class="tile one-by-one">test</div>
    <div class="tile one-by-two">test</div>
    <div class="tile two-by-two">test</div>
    <div class="tile one-by-one">test</div>
    <div class="tile one-by-one">test</div>
    <div class="tile one-by-one">test</div>
    <div class="tile one-by-one">test</div>
    <div class="tile three-by-two">test</div>
    <div class="tile one-by-one">test</div>
    <div class="tile two-by-one">test</div>
    <div class="tile two-by-one">test</div>
    <div class="tile one-by-one">test</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, but you're using `fr` units to size the columns. This means their widths are based on free space on the line. The less free space means the narrower the grid area. Maybe you can post an image with your desired layout on smaller screens.